# Should I put future talks on my CV?

Tags: job-search, cv, presentation

I am a Ph.D. student in mathematics, and I am currently applying for jobs. There are some talks that I will be giving later this month and the next few months. Should I put future, confirmed talks on my CV? If so, how should I denote that it is an upcoming talk?

Comment: Always consult with your adviser for the discipline-specific culture. I probably wouldn't put them on, unless they are invited talks.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is, in principle, nothing wrong for you to put these talks on your CV provided (i) they will really happen, and (ii) it is clear that they are in the future -- so put a (future) date next to them.

As a graduate student applying for jobs, you are in the same situation as all of the other graduate students: your CV is still pretty short. It is fair to add facts to it that will happen in the future (though it is, obviously, not ok to embellish by listing talks that you only *may* give but that may not in fact really happen).

Comment: If the talk was accepted for presentation at a conference based on a peer reviewed abstract, then there's somewhat more to it than just a planned presentation.  In that case, I'd state "Accepted for presentation at the 25th X conference."

Comment: I don't feel the necessity of the talks to *really happen* in the future. It is the same as the manuscripts under preparation or papers submitted to conferences or journals.